# Reduce number of cells in Excel

Tags: excel

I have a spreadsheet managing a list of groups in time slots. Imagine the below are cells:

```
0830-0845, Bob Hoskins, Jack Table, Phil Cup
0845-0900, Bob Hoskins, Jack Table, Phil Cup
0900-0915, Bob Hoskins, Jack Table, Phil Cup
0915-0930, Bob Hoskins, Jack Table, Phil Cup
0930-0945, Bob Hoskins, Jack Table, Phil Cup
0945-1000, Jane Dunnit, Henry Badass
1000-1015, Jane Dunnit, Henry Badass
1015-1030, Jane Dunnit, Henry Badass
1030-1045, Terry Turbo
1045-1100, Terry Turbo
1100-1115, Simon Car, Maggie Blah, Jack Paper
```

In a new sheet, within the workbook, What sort of formula can I use to squash the time slots together (Combine All values to get total Start to Finish)  and generate a sheet that looks more like this:

```
0830-0945, Bob Hoskins, Jack Table, Phil Cup
0945-1030, Jane Dunnit, Henry Badass
1030-1100, Terry Turbo
1100-1115, Simon Car, Maggie Blah, Jack Paper
```

The commas are the walls of cells, so the timestamps and names are in separate cells. This will need to be achieved using a formula as the source data will be updated regularly

Comment: How strict is the output? Can we have names all concatenated followed by new time range?

Comment: So you mean the timestamp in one cell and all the names in another cell? because that would be fine

Comment: Like "0830-0945" "Bob Hoskins, Jack Table, Phil Cup" quote marks are cell walls. The outputs for print so that solution would be fine

Comment: Alright that helps to create a simpler solution, take a look at mine and let me know if that helps/suffices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partial solution that is fairly easy to maintain using Pivot tables:

1. **Get start time column:**
   Add new column with formula: `=VALUE(MID(RC[-4],1,4))`
   Where RC[-4] is your original time range.
2. **Get end time column:**
   Add new column with formula: `=VALUE(MID(RC[-5],6,10))`
   Where RC[-5] is your original time range.
3. **Concatenated names column:**
   `=CONCATENATE(RC[-5],RC[-4],RC[-3])`
   Where RC[-5], RC[-4], RC[-3] are the cells with the name values.
   This is for grouping in Pivot Table.
   You should get something like this:
   [image: New extended table]
   Note headers are important!
4. **Insert a pivot table with your new extended table into a new worksheet:**
   Set row labels to name concatenation column.
   Add start time column as value, with value field setting as min
   Add end time column as value, with value field setting as max
   Set the number format of min of start and max of end as '0000' so it displays time correctly
   [image: Pivot table settings]

**In terms of maintainability:**

- Set a dynamic source range for your Pivot table (fairly easy to do).
- Update your extended columns by dragging formula or using hotkeys: ctrl+, ctrl+d to extend instead.
- Write a very simple macro to extend/update the extended columns for you.

**Simplifications/Assumptions:**

- Ordering of names is significant i.e. do not treat collection of names as a set

With excel, my advice is always to leverage existing tools as much as possible rather than use overly complicated cell formulas which can be hard to debug and possibly less efficient.

Let me know if this output is useful enough otherwise I'll see what else can be done.

Comment: Thank you @xlm but I'm stuck on stage one. I'm fairly newb at this. If the first timestamp was B2@ Where do I put **=VALUE(MID(RC[-4],1,4))** and how does it reference the timestamp cell?

Comment: I think this depends on your version of excel. Just replace RC[-4] with B2. Or you can use R2C2 (i.e. row 2, column 2).

Comment: Getting there. On the pivot table bit now

Comment: Let me know if you need more details on Pivot table settings etc. Hope it is going well for you.

Comment: @Tmdean +1 I remember spending time working out this one financial model done by a senior banker and in the end I realised they just recreated a Pivot table...

Comment: Wow, that was all new to me. Well done for coming up with such an excellent answer. So far this is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so very much. Just one small question, what can I add to **=CONCATENATE(C12:C22,D12:D22,E12:E22)** to get commas between the names?

Comment: Try `=CONCATENATE(C12:C22, ",", D12:D22, ",", E12:E22)`, I've added spaces to make it more clear

Comment: BTW I'm really glad it helped you and taught you how to get the most out of excel.

Answer (score 1):

I performed these steps as per Excel 2010, but this should work for other versions as well (with some minor changes).

**Steps:**

a) Select all data cells
b) Goto Data --> Data Tools --> Remove Duplicates
c) Seems that there are 4 columns in your data file, so in the popup you'll see 4 columns (say Column A, Column B, Column C, and Column D). Check all columns except Column A (i.e. where your timestamps exist). Press OK.

**Note:** In this solution, the first timestamp (and not the range) will show up for each unique line e.g.

```
0830-0845, Bob Hoskins, Jack Table, Phil Cup
0945-1000, Jane Dunnit, Henry Badass    
1030-1045, Terry Turbo      
1100-1115, Simon Car, Maggie Blah, Jack Paper
```

Comment: Only issue with that is it doesn't adjust the time stamp at the beginning.  There is also a chance the same names will show up later which would need to be combined seperatly.

Comment: I think you missed what the question was, He wants the left value of the first line with names, and the right value of the last row. So the first Row with `Bob Hoskins, Jack Table, Phil Cup` has time of `0830-0845` OP wants the 0830 from that and the last row for those names has  `0930-0945` and it looks like they want the `0945` from that and then combined to `0830-0945`

Comment: Thanks for taking a stab at it but it needs to flatten the repeated rows and update the timestamp like @user2140261 said. I have used an example to illustrate my problem, but I have a many hundreds of rows like this

Comment: This will need to be achieved using a formula as the source data will be frequently changed

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data starts in A2. Parse your input as Fixed Width to isolate the `-` and the first `,`. Select Text for the first and third columns. Format the sheet as General. In D2 put:

```
=IF(E1<>E2,"S",IF(E2<>E3,"F",""))
```

and copy down to suit.

Copy ColumnD, Paste Special, Values over the top and delete rows with blanks in Column D.
In B2 put:

```
=IF(AND(D2="S",D3="F"),A2&"-"&C3,IF(D2="S",A2&"-"&C2,""))
```

and copy down to suit.

Copy ColumnB, Paste Special, Values over the top and delete rows with blanks in Column B. In A2 put `=B2&", "&E2` and copy down to suit. Copy ColumnA, Paste Special, Values over the top.

Delete all but ColumnA.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion but the commas represent the walls of cells. The timestamp and names are in seperate cells.

Comment: I updated the question, I apologise for not making it clearer.

Comment: How do I d it without parsing? Will this formula update with source data? @pnuts