# delete an empty cell in pivot table in Excel

Tags: excel, filter, numbers, pivot-table

I used the answer @xlm gave me on [Reduce number of cells in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21172814/reduce-number-of-cells-in-excel) to make the below pivot table.

[image: 1]

How do I get the row with the blank cell to disappear?

Below is the dataset used to create the pivot table:

```
start,  end,    name,
830,    845,    ppa,
845,    900,    ppa,
900,    915,    Bob Hoskins liam Table,         
915,    930,    Bob Hoskins liam Table,        
930,    945,    Bob Hoskins liam Table,         
945,    1000,   Jack Door,          
1000,   1015,   Jack Door,          
1015,   1030,   Jack Door,          
1030,   1045,   Sara Car Tanya Coffee,      
1045,   1100,   Sara Car Tanya Coffee,      
1100,   1115,   Sara Car Tanya Coffee,      
1115,   1130,   Sara Car Tanya Coffee,      
1130,   1145,   Sara Car Tanya Coffee,      
1145,   1200,   Sara Car Tanya Coffee,      
1200,   1215,   Sara Car Tanya Coffee,      
1215,   1230,                  
1230,   1245,                  
1245,   1300,                  
1300,   1315,                  
1315,   1330,                  
1330,   1345,                  
1345,   1400,                  
1400,   1415,   Jack Whiskey,     
1415,   1430,   Jack Whiskey,     
1430,   1445,   Jack Whiskey,     
1445,   1500,   Jack Whiskey,     
1500,   1515,   Jack Whiskey,     
1515,   1530,
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filter out blanks from Pupils column (Click on the arrow and unselect "blank") and then PivotTable Tools/Options/Sort to sort by date.

Comment: Select table data without headers and then click on sort. It will prompt options, select Ascending and then the column name you want to reorder.