# sort times/number in pivot-table in Excel

Tags: excel, sorting, pivot-table

I used the answer @xlm gave me on [Reduce number of cells in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21172814/reduce-number-of-cells-in-excel) to make the below pivot table.

[image: 1]

How do I get the times in order? When I use sort this happens:

[image: 2]

Below is the dataset used to create the pivot table:

```
start,  end,    name,
830,    845,    ppa,
845,    900,    ppa,
900,    915,    Bob Hoskins liam Table,         
915,    930,    Bob Hoskins liam Table,        
930,    945,    Bob Hoskins liam Table,         
945,    1000,   Jack Door,          
1000,   1015,   Jack Door,          
1015,   1030,   Jack Door,          
1030,   1045,   Sara Car Tanya Coffee,      
1045,   1100,   Sara Car Tanya Coffee,      
1100,   1115,   Sara Car Tanya Coffee,      
1115,   1130,   Sara Car Tanya Coffee,      
1130,   1145,   Sara Car Tanya Coffee,      
1145,   1200,   Sara Car Tanya Coffee,      
1200,   1215,   Sara Car Tanya Coffee,      
1215,   1230,                  
1230,   1245,                  
1245,   1300,                  
1300,   1315,                  
1315,   1330,                  
1330,   1345,                  
1345,   1400,                  
1400,   1415,   Jack Whiskey,     
1415,   1430,   Jack Whiskey,     
1430,   1445,   Jack Whiskey,     
1445,   1500,   Jack Whiskey,     
1500,   1515,   Jack Whiskey,     
1515,   1530,
```

Comment: Look comment in [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21258832/delete-an-empty-cell-in-pivot-table-in-excel/21259103#21259103) to your previous question.

Comment: @hstay I did, which is why I rephrased the question and separated it, as the time wont filter as shown above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select table data without headers and then click on sort. It will prompt options, select Ascending and then the column name you want to reorder.

Comment: Fantastic! that was driving me nuts!